# MySQL Error by creating Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, delimiter

I want to make a Stored Procedure that handles an order from our site. The problem is that when I run the script there is a MySQL syntax error. I'm very new with MySQL Stored Procedures. Can someone look at my code?

```
USE postbrood;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE MaakBestelling(IN KlantIDParam INT, IN ProductIDArray VARCHAR(255), IN AantalArray VARCHAR(255))

BEGIN
DECLARE BestelID INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE ArrayLenght INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE Counter INT DEFAULT 0;



SET ArrayLenght = LENGTH(ProductIDArray) - LENGTH(REPLACE(ProductIDArray, ',', '')) + 1;


INSERT INTO bestelling(klantID) VALUES (KlantIDParam);
SET BestelID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

WHILE Counter < ArrayLenght DO
INSERT INTO bestelregel VALUES (SUBSTRING_INDEX(ProductIDArray,',',Counter),BestelID,SUBSTRING_INDEX(AantalArray,',',Counter));
SET Counter = Counter + 1;
END WHILE;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `END` is missing the delimiter you previously defined.  It should be `END //` not just `END`

Comment: **Next error**: 09:43:21 CREATE PROCEDURE MaakBestelling(IN KlantIDParam INT,  IN ProductIDArray VARCHAR(255), IN AantalArray VARCHAR(255))  BEGIN DECLARE BestelID INT DEFAULT 0 Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4 0.000 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nailed it! :)

```
USE postbrood;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE MaakBestelling(IN KlantIDParam INT, IN ProductIDArray VARCHAR(255), IN AantalArray VARCHAR(255))

BEGIN
DECLARE BestelID INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE ArrayLenght INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE Counter INT DEFAULT 0;



SET ArrayLenght = LENGTH(ProductIDArray) - LENGTH(REPLACE(ProductIDArray, ',', '')) + 1;


INSERT INTO bestelling(klantID) VALUES (KlantIDParam);
SET BestelID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

WHILE Counter < ArrayLenght DO
INSERT INTO bestelregel VALUES (SUBSTRING_INDEX(ProductIDArray,',',Counter),BestelID,SUBSTRING_INDEX(AantalArray,',',Counter),2.50);
SET Counter = Counter + 1;
END WHILE;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the comma is not being recognized at

```
SET ArrayLenght = LENGTH(ProductIDArray) - LENGTH(REPLACE(ProductIDArray, ',', '')) + 1;
```

You should try replacing the comma with the ascii entity number: `&#44;`